# Redirect non-www to www over reverse proxy with Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm having a bad day with Nginx.
I'm using Nginx reverse proxy because I'm going to host multiple Node.js applications on the same VPS, but I cannot find a way to redirect a non-www domain to its respective www.

I'm using the configurations inside conf.d folder...

## This is my colscript.mx.conf

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name     colscript.mx;
    return 301 $scheme://www.colscript.mx$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     www.colscript.mx;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

When I access the website through colscript.mx I can reach the website, but... when I use www.colscript.mx I get a server not found error.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I see no problem reaching it both wats

Comment: Yup I've just solved it by using.    server_name www.colscript.mx colscript.mx;

Comment: But there is no redirect

Comment: The "server not found" error given by browsers indicates problems with DNS entries.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

Just used

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     www.colscript.mx colscript.mx;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Both respond on same server but with no redirect.

Comment: Are you sure you want this? A redirect from non-www to www or viceversa would be better for SEO.